# kube-controller-manager - Failed to update statusUpdateNeeded field in actual state of world

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Troubleshooting Kuberenetes Controller Manager on why it is CrashLoopBackOff.
Installing Kubernetes on a cluster of Raspberry Pi 4 with 1 controller and 3 nodes running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

peter@k8s-controller:~/.kube$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-tsvqz                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (4m17s ago)    22m
kube-system    etcd-k8s-controller                      1/1     Running            600 (115s ago)   21h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-k8s-controller            1/1     Running            593 (11m ago)    21h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-k8s-controller   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   203 (115s ago)   20h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-k8s-controller            1/1     Running            647 (11m ago)    21h
```

peter@k8s-controller:~/.kube$ kubectl logs kube-controller-manager-k8s-controller -n kube-system

```
...
...
...
I1110 16:22:58.517816       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for PVC protection
I1110 16:22:58.525226       1 controllermanager.go:603] Started "pv-protection"
I1110 16:22:58.525257       1 pv_protection_controller.go:79] Starting PV protection controller
I1110 16:22:58.525522       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for PV protection
I1110 16:22:58.534018       1 controllermanager.go:603] Started "ttl-after-finished"
I1110 16:22:58.534077       1 ttlafterfinished_controller.go:109] Starting TTL after finished controller
I1110 16:22:58.534108       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for TTL after finished
I1110 16:22:58.550100       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for resource quota
W1110 16:22:58.610360       1 topologycache.go:199] Can't get CPU or zone information for k8s-controller node
W1110 16:22:58.610536       1 actual_state_of_world.go:541] Failed to update statusUpdateNeeded field in actual state of world: Failed to set statusUpdateNeeded to needed true, because nodeName="k8s-controller" does not exist
I1110 16:22:58.612600       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for namespace
I1110 16:22:58.635687       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for TTL after finished
I1110 16:22:58.636740       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for job
I1110 16:22:58.637004       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for ReplicationController
I1110 16:22:58.648184       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for TTL
I1110 16:22:58.648792       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for GC
I1110 16:22:58.652498       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for service account
I1110 16:22:58.655279       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for ephemeral
I1110 16:22:58.659445       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for HPA
I1110 16:22:58.667718       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for endpoint
I1110 16:22:58.675049       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for disruption
I1110 16:22:58.680819       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for deployment
I1110 16:22:58.685501       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for garbage collector
I1110 16:22:58.688483       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for bootstrap_signer
I1110 16:22:58.695221       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for stateful set
I1110 16:22:58.704792       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for certificate-csrsigning-kube-apiserver-client
I1110 16:22:58.704801       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for certificate-csrsigning-kubelet-client
I1110 16:22:58.704825       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for certificate-csrsigning-legacy-unknown
I1110 16:22:58.706270       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for certificate-csrsigning-kubelet-serving
I1110 16:22:58.707386       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for node
I1110 16:22:58.707740       1 range_allocator.go:166] Starting range CIDR allocator
I1110 16:22:58.708082       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for cidrallocator
I1110 16:22:58.708153       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for cidrallocator
I1110 16:22:58.711996       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for attach detach
I1110 16:22:58.718755       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for PVC protection
I1110 16:22:58.722062       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for endpoint_slice
I1110 16:22:58.724007       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for persistent volume
I1110 16:22:58.726148       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for PV protection
I1110 16:22:58.726262       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for certificate-csrapproving
I1110 16:22:58.729015       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for expand
I1110 16:22:58.729030       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for ClusterRoleAggregator
I1110 16:22:58.732808       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for endpoint_slice_mirroring
I1110 16:22:58.735349       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for ReplicaSet
I1110 16:22:58.748800       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for crt configmap
I1110 16:22:58.753494       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for resource quota
I1110 16:22:58.757920       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for taint
I1110 16:22:58.758026       1 taint_manager.go:204] "Starting NoExecuteTaintManager"
I1110 16:22:58.758150       1 taint_manager.go:209] "Sending events to api server"
I1110 16:22:58.758381       1 node_lifecycle_controller.go:1443] Initializing eviction metric for zone: 
W1110 16:22:58.758746       1 node_lifecycle_controller.go:1058] Missing timestamp for Node k8s-controller. Assuming now as a timestamp.
I1110 16:22:58.758999       1 node_lifecycle_controller.go:1259] Controller detected that zone  is now in state Normal.
I1110 16:22:58.760584       1 event.go:294] "Event occurred" object="k8s-controller" fieldPath="" kind="Node" apiVersion="v1" type="Normal" reason="RegisteredNode" message="Node k8s-controller event: Registered Node k8s-controller in Controller"
I1110 16:22:58.785567       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for cronjob
I1110 16:22:58.807169       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for resource quota
I1110 16:22:58.828857       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for daemon sets
I1110 16:22:59.179412       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for garbage collector
I1110 16:22:59.179491       1 garbagecollector.go:163] Garbage collector: all resource monitors have synced. Proceeding to collect garbage
I1110 16:22:59.186566       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for garbage collector
```

peter@k8s-controller:~/.kube$ kubectl describe pod kube-controller-manager-k8s-controller -n kube-system

```
Name:                 kube-controller-manager-k8s-controller
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Node:                 k8s-controller/192.168.1.135
Start Time:           Wed, 09 Nov 2022 17:17:37 +0000
Labels:               component=kube-controller-manager
                      tier=control-plane
Annotations:          kubernetes.io/config.hash: b532fabbdf0b07ab27260611cd331d12
                      kubernetes.io/config.mirror: b532fabbdf0b07ab27260611cd331d12
                      kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2022-11-09T17:17:37.146676661Z
                      kubernetes.io/config.source: file
Status:               Running
IP:                   192.168.1.135
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.1.135
Controlled By:  Node/k8s-controller
Containers:
  kube-controller-manager:
    Container ID:  containerd://3f089008e9d82a6e6a6565ab124f7099d3532836df4dbc0fb058bcbdac355840
    Image:         registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.3
    Image ID:      registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager@sha256:d3a06262256f3e7578d5f77df137a8cdf58f9f498f35b5b56d116e8a7e31dc91
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      kube-controller-manager
      --allocate-node-cidrs=true
      --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      --bind-address=127.0.0.1
      --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --cluster-cidr=192.168.1.1/16
      --cluster-name=kubernetes
      --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key
      --controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner
      --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      --leader-elect=true
      --leader-elect-lease-duration=60s
      --leader-elect-renew-deadline=30s
      --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
      --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
      --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
      --use-service-account-credentials=true
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Thu, 10 Nov 2022 13:35:46 +0000
      Finished:     Thu, 10 Nov 2022 13:35:57 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  203
    Requests:
      cpu:        200m
    Liveness:     http-get https://127.0.0.1:10257/healthz delay=10s timeout=15s period=10s #success=1 #failure=8
    Startup:      http-get https://127.0.0.1:10257/healthz delay=10s timeout=15s period=10s #success=1 #failure=24
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/ca-certificates from etc-ca-certificates (ro)
      /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf from kubeconfig (ro)
      /etc/kubernetes/pki from k8s-certs (ro)
      /etc/pki from etc-pki (ro)
      /etc/ssl/certs from ca-certs (ro)
      /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec from flexvolume-dir (rw)
      /usr/local/share/ca-certificates from usr-local-share-ca-certificates (ro)
      /usr/share/ca-certificates from usr-share-ca-certificates (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  ca-certs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/ssl/certs
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  etc-ca-certificates:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/ca-certificates
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  etc-pki:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/pki
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  flexvolume-dir:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  k8s-certs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/kubernetes/pki
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  kubeconfig:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    HostPathType:  FileOrCreate
  usr-local-share-ca-certificates:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  usr-share-ca-certificates:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/ca-certificates
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
QoS Class:         Burstable
Node-Selectors:    <none>
Tolerations:       :NoExecute op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------          ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy       13h                    kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "https://127.0.0.1:10257/healthz": read tcp 127.0.0.1:44478->127.0.0.1:10257: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy       5h25m (x8 over 17h)    kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "https://127.0.0.1:10257/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10257: connect: connection refused
  Normal   SandboxChanged  3h2m (x129 over 20h)   kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Created         168m (x177 over 20h)   kubelet  Created container kube-controller-manager
  Normal   Started         168m (x177 over 20h)   kubelet  Started container kube-controller-manager
  Normal   Pulled          100m (x187 over 20h)   kubelet  Container image "registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Killing         5m20s (x149 over 20h)  kubelet  Stopping container kube-controller-manager
  Warning  BackOff         27s (x3064 over 20h)   kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```